# Is it possible to sort a an array list while ignoring the first 3 characters in each string?

Tags: java, sorting, linked-list

I am trying to figure out how to sort my list alphabetically, normally this would be really easy, but I need to ignore the first 5 characters of each string in my list. (they are numerical IDS)

```
        ArrayList<String> tempList = new ArrayList<String>();

        for(String s : AddressBook){
        tempList.add(s);

        Collections.sort(tempList );

            }
        System.out.println(tempList);
```

Comment: If you give some example here then it would be easy to understand your problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it by supplying your own Comparator implementation.

```
Collections.sort (tempList, new Comparator<String>() {
  public int compare(String o1, String o2)
  {
    String sub1 = o1.substring (3);
    String sub2 = o2.substring (3);
    return sub1.compareTo (sub2);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is fairly trivial in Java 8:

```
Collections.sort(list, Comparator.comparing(s -> s.subString(4));
```

Comment: Is that psedocode, I tried using it in my source and my compiler doesn't like it.

Comment: Lambda expression, you'd have Java8

Answer (score 1):

This answer applies for Java 8, improving performance and readability by using lambda expressions.

You might need to apply special string length checks (if your implementation provides Strings shorter than 6 characters).

```
Collections.sort (tempList, (o1, o2) -> o1.substring(5).compareTo(o2.substring(5)));
```

Comment: is it possible to do that without using java 8? the unix system im trying to compile it on doesn't like that line of code.