# How to ignore first Word when Sorting

Tags: java, android, sorting

I have a `List` of `Strings` and I want to sort them:

```
ICD10DatabaseHandler icd10Helper = new ICD10DatabaseHandler(getActivity());
            icd10Helper.open();
            List<Strings> icd10Favorites = icd10Helper.getFavoriteIcd10Tags();
            Collections.sort(icd10Favorites);
            icd10Helper.close();
            return true;
```

My problem is my `List` have a `id` before the `description` and what I want to produce is a sort of the the `List` ignoring the first word ( `id`) of the element.

**Actual output**

```
A000 Cholera due to Vibrio cholerae 01 
A010 Typhoid fever with heart involvement
A012 Paratyphoid fever B
```

**Desired Output:**

```
A000 Cholera due to Vibrio cholerae 01 
A012 Paratyphoid fever B
A010 Typhoid fever with heart involvement
```

Comment: I'd go with that solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33063218/is-it-possible-to-sort-a-an-array-list-while-ignoring-the-first-3-characters-in (if you don't know the length of first word, then cut to the first space).

Comment: Use your own `Comparator` implementation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you cannot use java8, you need to define your own [**`Comparator`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html), for example:

```
class MyComparator<T> implements Comparator<String> {
    private static String getDescription(String s) {
        // get all String after CODE
        String[] all = s.split(" ", 2);

        // if there is some content
        if (all.length >= 2) 
            // get it in LOWER CASE
            return all[1].toLowerCase();
        else 
            return "";
    }

    public int compare(String s0, String s1) {
        return getDescription(s0).compareTo(getDescription(s1));
    }

}
```

---

**USE**

```
Collections.sort(elements, new MyComparator<String>());
```

**NOTE:** *if you must use several times, create an instance instead instantiating on the fly*

---

**TEST IT**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("BEFORE SORTING");
    printList(elements);

    Collections.sort(elements, new MyComparator<String>());

    System.out.println("\nAFTER SORTING");
    printList(elements);
}

private static void printList(List<String> list) {
    for (String s : list) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }

}
```

**RESULTS:**

```
BEFORE SORTING
A012 Paratyphoid fever B
A010 Typhoid fever with heart involvement
A000 Cholera due to Vibrio cholerae 01

AFTER SORTING
A000 Cholera due to Vibrio cholerae 01
A012 Paratyphoid fever B
A010 Typhoid fever with heart involvement
```

Comment: Thanks @Jordi. may ask what i supposed to add if i want it to be not cased sensitive. thanks.

Comment: sure, check my edit, I also changed the way I splitted the String to get ALL String except CODE in this way you will sort more accurate.

Answer (score 3):

```
Collections.sort(
    list,
    (a, b) -> a.split(" *", 2)[1].compareTo( b.split(" *", 2)[1] )
);
```

Requires Java 8 for the lambda, which splits the strings on the first space in the sentence and compares what comes after it.

This is not defined if the strings don't have at least two words in. Also performance during comparison could be argued to be non-ideal.